# Will packages work with older Ubuntu releases?

Tags: apt, dpkg

E.g., will Natty packages work on Maverick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on package dependencies, in general is not safe to use packages from different releases, even when they can be installed they may cause packaging conflicts and other unexpected issues.